# Ubuntu 22.04.3 Installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb

I'm an absolute beginner. I made my USB of 8GB bootable with the Ubuntu ISO mentioned version. I have Windows 10 Pro already installed on my System. I have three drives, (C) has Windows, (D) has my data and (E) I created for Ubuntu to be installed on.

I inserted the USB and got to the Installation process. I used the following guide: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-type-of-installation

It says I can use Windows and Ubuntu both on my system. Unfortunately, upon installation process, the option "Installing Ubuntu alongside another operating system" doesn't appear. Only the other two options appear. How do I install it on my Drive E?

When I chose the Manual Partitioning option, I selected a drive (that didn't have the name E) but the same storage space, I selected it but it has several options to select for installation. FAT 32 or NFT but it doesn't proceed as it asks for a root address (I don't know what it is).

Can anyone explain how I can install Ubuntu on my Drive E?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: It's probably easier to delete the E partition from Windows. Ubuntu *should* display the "install alongside another operating system" option. If it doesn't then yes, you might need to manually partition.